# How to stop redirecting locally hosted iis websites

Tags: iis

So I've setup a website in IIS to point to a folder that contains index.html. 
I named the site as productmanagement.com with IP address all unassigned and port set to the default 80. Now when I try to go to http://productmanagement.com, it'll goto some other website and not hit my index. What do I do to tell it to hit that?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. After further researching I found out that I had to edit the hosts file. After pointing my IP address to the site name, it worked.